# Let $A,B$ be subgroups of a group $G$. Prove $AB$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $AB=BA$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A,B$ be subgroups of a group $G$. Prove $AB$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $AB=BA$

Could someone explain/define the multiplication here for me so that I may attempt this problem. Thank you

I know that a group does not have the commutative property in it, just associative, inverse and indentity.

Comment: $AB = \{y \in G \; \vert \; y = ab, a\in A, b\in B\}$, that is, the elements in $AB$ are of the form $ab$, with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$.

Comment: @Miguelgondu, kinda like the Cartesian products (a,b), where a is in A and b is in B?

Comment: how could you really generally prove that unless a or b was the identity?

Comment: Join this chat, please: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20995/room-for-celas-doubts

Comment: I think you need to open an account for the chat system.

Comment: @cele Maybe an example helps you to understand the complex product: let $G=S_3$, $A=\{id, (12)\}$ and $B=\{id,(13)\}$. Then $AB=\{id\circ id, (12)\circ id, id\circ (13), (12)\circ (13)\}=\{id, (12),(13),(132)\}$. You have to take the set of all possible products $a\circ b$ (in the correct order) with $a\in A,b\in B$. In the present example, the constituents $A$ and $B$ are groups but $AB\ne BA$ hence $AB$ is not a subgroup; the definition of this product applies to all subsets of $G$.

Comment: @cele Added to the last comment: Perhaps you have encountered this "product" in linear algebra: as "sum" of subsets and subspaces of vector spaces.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $AB=BA$ we have $(a_1b_1)(a_2b_2)=(a_1b_1)(b_3a_3)=(a_1b_4)a_3=(b_5a_4)a_3=b_5a_5=a_6b_6$

and we have $(a_1b_1)^{-1}=b_1^{-1}a_1^{-1}=a_2b_2$.

If $AB$ is a subgroup:

$BA\subseteq AB$: $ba=(a^{-1}b^{-1})^{-1}$ which is in $AB$ since $AB$ is a subgroup containing $a^{-1}b^{-1}$

$AB\subseteq BA$: $ab$ is the inverse of $a_1b_1$, So $ab=(a_1b_1)^{-1}=b_1^{-1}a_1^{-1}\in BA$

Comment: the comment about me not knowing group theory was correct. I am beginning and a lot of the notation confuses me. I am not sure how you are doing the multiplication above.

Comment: It is the a*a, b*b correct? or was I incorrect in my assumption that it is much like Cartesian products?

Comment: multiplication takes place inside the group. The deal here is that the elements of $AB$ are the elements of $G$ of the form $ab$ with $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. So for example $(a_1b_1)(a_2b_2)$ is just $a_1b_1a_2b_2$ multiplied in the usual way elements of the group $G$ are multiplied.

Comment: Cartesian products return ordered pairs, $(a,b)$.  "Products" in this case are more simply $a\circ b$ where $\circ$ is the operation for the group.  Most times we opt to write it down in the same way we would for "multiplication" in the usual sense, borrowing notation and names from that, even if it could be fundamentally different than the "multiplication" we are used to.

Comment: I still don't get it. I'll keep working on it. Thanks for the hlep