# Direct product and group generated by subgroups

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product, direct-product

Lets have two subgroups $A$ and $B$ of given group $G$. We have their product defined the following way:
$$AB=\{ab\,|\, a\in A,\, b\in B \}$$
But, unfortunately, this product is not always a group.
Suppose we have another set $C$ that is defined the following way:
$$C=\{ab\,|\, (a\in A \lor a\in B) \land (b\in A \lor b\in B) \}$$
Obviously, $C$ is a group because $C \cong A \times B$ and it is a subgroup of $G$.
The question is: whether there exists a math term for this subgroup product so I could find more information about in order to figure out the proof for Cauchy theorem by myself.

Comment: The set $C$ you defined is not a subgroup either (in general).

Comment: The set $C$ is **not** necessarily isomorphic to $A\times B$. Your set $C$ is equal to $A^2\cup AB\cup BA\cup B^2=A\cup B\cup AB\cup BA$, which need not be a group either.

Comment: I mean, if $A=B$, then your set $C$ would just be $A$, but you claim it is isomorphic to $A\times A$. Surely you see that this cannot be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "math term" for $G=AB$ is [factorizable groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316233/factorizable-groups). There is a large literature on such groups. One open question is, whether or not any dinilpotent group $G=AB$, which is the product of two nilpotent subgroups $A$ and $B$, is solvable - see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125048/are-all-dinilpotent-groups-solvable-i-e-groups-g-ab-with-nilpotent-subgroups).

By the way, $AB$ is a group if and only if $AB=BA$:

[Let $A,B$ be subgroups of a group $G$. Prove $AB$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $AB=BA$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141436/let-a-b-be-subgroups-of-a-group-g-prove-ab-is-a-subgroup-of-g-if-and-on)