# What's the condition for a group $G$ to be equal to the product of two normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

If $G$ is a group and $N,M$ are two normal subgroups. We know that the product $NM$ is normal subgroup of $G$, but when can I say that $G=NM$. What must be the conditions on $N,M$?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all groups mentioned in these examples are finite.
An example: if $|G:M|$ and $|G:N|$ are *coprime*, then $G=NM$. Proof: $|G:NM| \mid |G:M|$ and $|G:NM| \mid |G:N|$. 
Another example: if $|M|$ and $|N|$ are *coprime* and $|G|=|N| \cdot |M|$, then $G=NM$.
Yet another example: if $M$ is a *maximal* subgroup and $N \not \subseteq M$, then $G=NM$.

If you are familar with *(ordinary) character theory of finite groups*: if $\varphi$ is a character of $M$ and the induction-restriction $(\varphi^G)_N$ is irreducible, then $G=NM$.

Comment: The second example is not valid.

Comment: @Berci $gcd(|M|,|N|)=1$ implies $M \cap N=1$, so $|NM|=\frac{|M| \cdot |N|}{|M \cap N|}=|G|$, whence $G=NM$.

Comment: Ah ok, I didn't realize the condition '*and* $|G|=|M|\cdot|N|$...

Answer (score 1):

There is a more general question, which has been studied intensively, namely when can we say that $G=AB$ for subgroups $A,B$? Such groups $G$ are called *factorizable* and there is a large literature about them.

There are some trivial conditions, for example, that $AB$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $AB=BA$, see

[Let $A,B$ be subgroups of a group $G$. Prove $AB$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $AB=BA$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141436/let-a-b-be-subgroups-of-a-group-g-prove-ab-is-a-subgroup-of-g-if-and-on)

References on factorizable groups: for example [Arad](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjm4PPP9OPtAhXpzIUKHUi-DqAQFjABegQIAxAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcore.ac.uk%2Fdownload%2Fpdf%2F82597269.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0gSBTFsqZVXAiGrxaZo0ur), and many papers by Amberg,B. Franciosi, S. and Degiovanni and others, also papers by [Gorenstein, Herstein](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2033626#metadata_info_tab_contents).

For more references see also [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/316233/factorizable-groups).

Comment: but here we only consider the normal subgroup

Comment: Yes, I know. I said "There is a more general question". And this is quite interesting for general subgroups $A,B$. Of course, it is all valid for normal subgroups, too, and complements Nicky's answer.

Comment: Napu, I hope you'll enjoy reading a bit further for the context concerning  factorizable $G=AB$. This site is also there to get you excited about new things (and not only helping with homework).